# How to access mongodb like local

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I build system with docker to test in local.

Also use docker-compose to tie all image to one infra.

Below is images that I used.

- nginx:latest
- mongo:latest
- ubuntu:latest
- python:3.6.5

(python for flask web application)

[docker-compose.yml]

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  nginx:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/nginx/dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    hostname: nginx-dev
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    networks: 
      - backend

  mongodb:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/mongodb/dockerfile
    container_name: mongodb
    hostname: mongodb-dev
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    networks:
      - backend

  web_project:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/web/dockerfile
    container_name: web_project
    hostname: web_project_dev
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    networks:
      - backend
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    links:
      - mongodb

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis_dev

networks: 
  backend:
    driver: 'bridge'
```

[mongo's dockerfile]

```
FROM mongo:latest

EXPOSE 27017
```

[python's dockerfile]

```
FROM python:3.6.5

COPY . ./home
WORKDIR home
RUN pip install -r app/requirements.txt
CMD python manage.py run
```

When I run my python flask web app in local, it works fine because mongodb is located in local too.

But I run with `docker-compose up`, it can't access to mongodb.

Maybe every docker image was separated.

I think I have to tiny each image to access to other.

But I'm new at docker so confuse with it.

Is there any solution here?

Thanks.

Comment: You already did port publishing in compose file for MongoDB. Technically, you could access it with localhost:27017 on host. But you cannot access it with localhost:27017 in web_project container, since localhost means the web_project container itself, not mongodb container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[SOLVED]*

I modified `'host': 'mongodb-dev:27017'` to `'host': 'mongodb-:27017'`,

and it works perfectly.

I think it happends by links: mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you reference your Mongo in your Flask app with the hostname `mongodb-dev` instead of `localhost`

Comment: I modified `'host': 'localhost:27017'` to  `'host': 'mongodb-dev:27017'` at my flask code, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: error code -> `pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongodb-dev:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Comment: I think you are putting the port into a field which should only contain the hostname, try: `'host': 'mongodb-dev`'

Comment: I modified `'host': 'mongodb-dev:27017'` to `'host': 'mongodb-:27017'`, and it works perfectly. I think it happends by `links: mongodb`. Anyway, thanks for reply.